# How to setup the environment for the sample sp-dev-fx-webparts - client-side web part samples

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, npm

I have installed git and cloned the below
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples
Installed node and NPM for windows.Ran **npm install** for just one specific folder (react-script-editor) ..this is where i stopped for now

But the question is what would be the process to be able to deploy some specific webparts to my tenant and also get my environment ready to be able to create new projects and at the same time deploy the samples.

I can't find any step by step process to install this webparts and what are the dependencies ?

Any guide or resources would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

1. Copy a single/specific folder corresponding the web-part you want to use.
2. Open that folder in Node JS command prompt.
3. Run the command: `npm install`.
4. Run the command: `gulp build`.
5. If there are any errors in code then fix it.
6. If you see any error while importing libraries then you need to install those using npm.
7. Run the command: `gulp bundle --ship`.
8. Run the command: `gulp package-solution --ship`.

**official documentation**:

1. [Overview of the SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview).
2. [Host your client-side web part from Office 365 CDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/hosting-webpart-from-office-365-cdn).

Comment: thanks Ganesh. Which node version though? I currently have the up  to date version of @microsoft/generator-sharepoint 1.9.1. But i'm getting error saying its not compatible with the current node version which is 12.xxx

Comment: I would recommend you to use Node Version 10.xx and @microsoft/generator-sharepoint 1.8

Comment: Thanks . When i check my node version  using node -v it returns  v10.17.0, When i do npm -v its 6.13.2 . Does this have to be the same version? If yes how can i get npm to the 10.17.0?

Comment: No, npm version and Node version is different. However you can upgrade npm to latest version using `npm install -g npm@latest`.

Comment: Hi @naijacoder, Did you solved this issue? Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you so that this question will not be shown under unanswered questions list on this platform.